# How to align a div to bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a chat webpage using Python Flask as a backend. I want to align messages that are received and sent recently to be aligned in the bottom and when new ones arrive that msg should move up and new ones should be placed in that place. How to do that? I have read similar questions but couldn't understand how to implement it for my needs.

My chat page structure is as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{
      url_for('static', filename = 'static/css/jquery/jquery.js')
    }
    }
    ">\x3C/script>')
  </script>
  <script type=text/javascript>
    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {
      {
        request.script_root | tojson | safe
      }
    };
    $(function() {
      $('#send_btn').bind('click', function() {

        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/serve_msg', {
          msg: $('input[name="msg"]').val(),
        }, function(data) {
          var msg = document.createElement('div');
          msg.className = 'msg';
          msg.innerHTML = '<img src="" alt="You"><p id="send_msg"> document.getElementById("msg").value </p><span class="time-left">11:00</span>';
          document.getElementById('msg_box').appendChild(msg);
          $('#send_msg').text($('input[name="msg"]').val())
          $("#reply").text(data.reply);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="webi/templates/style.css">-->
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #2a4982;
    }
    
    .container {
      border: 2px solid #dedede;
      background-color: #555555;
      border-radius: 5px;
      align-self: center;
      padding-bottom: 3%;
      margin-top: 4%;
      margin-left: 16%;
      margin-right: 10%;
    }
    
    .chatbox {
      border: 2px solid #dedede;
      background-color: #cac6f1;
      border-radius: 5px;
      align-self: center;
      padding-bottom: 6%;
      margin-left: 15%;
      margin-right: 15%;
    }
    
    .main_heading {
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #2981bc;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1px cornsilk;
      padding-top: -8%;
      padding-bottom: -8%;
    }
    
    .text_input_area {
      margin-top: 1%;
      margin-bottom: -1%;
    }
    
    .msg_box {
      position: relative;
      background: rgb(22, 29, 34);
      /*padding-bottom: 50%;*/
      height: 450px;
      width: 770px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    .msg_input {
      width: 85%;
      padding-bottom: 3%;
    }
    
    .msg_sent {}
    
    .msg_recieved {}
    /* Style time text */
    
    .time-right {
      float: right;
      color: #aaa;
    }
    /* Style time text */
    
    .time-left {
      float: left;
      color: #999;
    }
    
    .msg {
      position: relative;
      ;
      border: 2px solid #dedede;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      border-radius: 5px;
      height: 40px;
      width: fit-content;
      margin: 15px 0;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    /* Darker chat container */
    
    .msg_recieved {
      border-color: #ccc;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    /* Clear floats */
    
    .container::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }
    /* Style images */
    
    .container img {
      float: left;
      max-width: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-right: 20px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    /* Style the right image */
    
    .container img.right {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <title>AVE - WEB INTERFACE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" align="center">
    <p class="main_heading"> AVE - AI Virtual Entity</p>
    <div class="chatbox">
      chatbox
      <div class="msg_box">
        <div class="msg msg_recieved">
          <img src="" alt="Ave">
          <p id="reply">Hello. How are you today?</p>
          <span class="time-right">11:00</span>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here!" aria-label="input_area" aria-describedby="send_btn">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="send_btn" onclick="display_send_msg">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for the bad code! I am new to this whole idea. There may be lots of errors. Sorry for that

Comment: Welcome on SO: please show your attempt, explain how do you update the DOM, insert a snippet with the markup structure in the question.

Comment: Have you seen the answers below? Did you solve?

Comment: yes. I have somehow figured out how to do it. below answers helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you have a basic markup structure like

```
<main id="msgs">
   <div>Message #0</div>
   <div>Message #1</div>
   <div>Message #2</div>
   <div>Message #3</div>
   <div>Message #4</div>
   <!-- new messages are appended here -->
</main>
```

Using Flexbox you could place them in reverse order so every new message is visible on top of the page

```
main {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
}
```

Then via Javascript, once you appended the new message you need to scroll the main element via `scrollTo(0, 0);` The scroll could even be improved via CSS with `scroll-behavior: smooth;`

Here below a snippet that simulates a new message every `5s`:

---

```js
var messageArea = document.getElementById('msgs');
messageArea.scrollTo(0, 0);

setInterval(() => {
  /* create a new message element */
  var msgEl = document.createElement('div');
  /* create a string with the message */
  var msgText = 'Message #' + messageArea.children.length;
  /* set the textContent of the element with the message */
  msgEl.textContent = msgText;
  /* append the new message in the container of the messages */
  messageArea.appendChild(msgEl);
   
  /* finally scroll the message area to (0, 0) coords. */
  messageArea.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, 5000)
```

```css
main {
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   overflow: auto;
   padding: 1em .5em;
   flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

div {
   border: 1px #ccc solid;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 1em;
   margin-top: 1.5em;
   width:60%;
   align-self: flex-start;
}

div:nth-child(2n) {
   align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<main id="msgs">
   <div>Message #0</div>
   <div>Message #1</div>
   <div>Message #2</div>
   <div>Message #3</div>
   <div>Message #4</div>
</main>
```

Comment: thanks, I have figured out a solution from your answer. the issue is solved now thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to just normally append new message to the messages div and use JavaScript/jQuery to scroll to bottom of that div.

jQuery:

```
$('.messages').scrollTop($('.messages').height())
```